# iPhone - UITableView background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, background-image

I want to give a background image to my UITableView, so I tried this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[v setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:v];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack: v];
...
}
```

This works fine. However, after pushViewController, this method doesn't work anymore (why?). So I changed a method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super loadView];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
...
}
```

This can work, but the result is not what I expected. Somehow the background picture changes its size (like a partial enlargement), and the background of cells is darker than the previous one.

Anyone knows the reason? I've been stuck with this problem for a long time.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show my answer. you add image view in tableview .not in view

Comment: try your code in viewWillAppear: that will work you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code i am sure it'll work

```
UIImage * targetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coloured_flower.jpg"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.frame.size, NO, 0.f);
[targetImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)];
UIImage * resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:resultImage];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBackground.jpg"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = background;
[background release];
```

**Edit:**

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBackground.jpg"];
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:myImage];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = background;
[background release];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but this still cannot work. I copied what you said, and the compiler shows "Incompatible pointer types sending UIImageView* to parameter of type UIImage*"

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableView *tblView=[[UITableView alloc] init];
[tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];


UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:tblView.frame];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cinemax.jpg"]];
tblView.backgroundView=imgView;

[self.view addSubview:tblView];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But this works weird... Totally blocked the table, and frame of tblView is not the right size

Comment: this is imageView u can resize it to tableView frame.then what type of problem you are facing I didn't understand completely.pls elaborate this line "Totally blocked the table" or show me some screenshot

Comment: Yeah I get the size. Sorry I cannot upload screenshot... just the background picture comes in front of the tableview

Comment: Nevermind, I got the problem. I used a different tableview. My fault. Thanks a lot!